# Using OpenLayers WFS filter by DATE?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs

Using openlayers, I would like to create a temporal filter to query a GeoServer WFS service.

There is a WFS filter example here without the temporal (date) portion that i need:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-filter.html

My dates on GeoServer are stored in the following format: "2010-09-12 08:10:40+00"

I seek any links or code snippets that might help me?

Comment: [Here it is](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/filter-strategy.html)!

Comment: This looks very promising thank you. I'm going to test it out and give you the credit as soon as i get it working +1.